# How to pay out to a bank account using Stripe?

Tags: stripe-payments, payment

I have a site where I am using Stripe API to collect payments. I would like to send some amount of the money I collect to a user's bank account. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't simply send funds to any bank account from your own Stripe account.

You can use [Stripe Connect](https://stripe.com/connect) to accept payments on behalf of others (and optionally take a fee for yourself), then send funds to their bank account. But there a lot of things to consider when using Connect and it's quite a lot more complex than simply using Stripe for yourself.

If it sounds like Connect is a good fit for you, I greatly recommend you spend some time to read [the docs](https://stripe.com/docs/connect) as well as [this article](https://support.stripe.com/questions/considerations-for-platforms-using-connect).